# Specific if-statements regarding a roll of five dice

Tags: java, if-statement

The following code shows a simple roll of five dice.

If any two dice are matching, and the three other are also matching, I'd like to give the sum of the rolls. However, I'm not quite sure how to represent that while using an if statement.

> Example: 4 4 3 4 3

Additionally, I'd like to figure out the same if the values of the dice can be arranged in a continuous wraparound sequence, (1 follows after 6).

> Example: 6 1 2 3 4

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!

```
    int die1;   
    int die2;          
    int die3;   
    int die4;
    int die5;
    int roll;

    die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    die3 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    die4 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    die5 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;

    System.out.print("The roll was : " + die1 + " " + die2 + " " + die3 + " " + die4 + " " + die5 + " ");
```

Comment: you should add the die to a list so you can iterate over them

Answer (score 0):

Putting your rolls into an `ArrayList<Integer>` will make things much easier for you. Assuming we have that, we can use `Stream`:

```
Collection<Long> counts = rollList.stream()                     //Stream<Integer>
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( //Group to Map
                                 Function.identity(),           //Key = The roll itself
                                 Collectors.counting()))        //Value = How many were rolled
                                .values()                       //Values only

if(counts.contains(2) && counts.contains(3)) { //One rolled twice, other thrice
    int total = rollList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum(); //Sum of all rolls
    System.out.println("You rolled a full house with a total value of "+total);

else if(counts.size() == 5) //If all rolls were different, it was definitely a straight because there are 6 wrapping values and 5 rolls
    System.out.println("You rolled a straight");
```

You can also just put the values directly into an `IntStream`, I think.